# Discord.js messege is not defined

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

I am trying to make my first bot but for some reason I am getting this error.
I am very new to this so please don't be toxic <3

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login('token');
//reading
client.on('message', message => {
    console.log(message.content);
});
//youtube channel command
if (message.content === '!yt'&&'!youtube') {
    message.channel.send('yt channel');
}
//--------------------
```

ERROR

```
ReferenceError: message is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\NoVirusesAllowed\Desktop\Discord Bot\index.js:14:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)

    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Comment: Your youtube channel command comes after the closing bracket and parenthesis for your message handler. You can tell this because 1. you can see the closing bracket on the previous line and 2. the indentation level is that of the top-level (code that will run synchronously when the bot starts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`message` is not part of the function where it's defined.
Because the variable is defined locally, other functions won't be able to access it.

You likely want to move the `if` statement inside the `client.on()` block, as this will execute on every message.

With your current code, the `if` statement attempts to execute once at the start of the script, and doesn't know what message its referring to.

EDIT: I've also modified the condition in the `if` statement.
Before, the condition would succeed if the message was `'!yt'` and `'!youtube'` was none zero.
You likely want the condition to succeed if either the message is equal to either `'!yt'` or `'!youtube'`, which can be done with an OR operator `||`.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login('token');
//reading
client.on('message', message => {
    console.log(message.content);

    //youtube channel command
    if (message.content == '!yt' || message.content == '!youtube') {
        message.channel.send('yt channel');
    }
});
//--------------------
```